# RX Repeat after all subscribers finished

Tags: c#, system.reactive

Is there a way in RX to observe form async using repeat and also calling for next message only after all subscribes finished?
Example:

```
var messages = new Stack<int>(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 });

var observable = Observable
    .FromAsync(() => Task.Run(() => messages.Peek()))
    .Repeat(6);

observable.Subscribe(async message =>
{
    await Task.Delay(2);
    Console.WriteLine(message);
    messages.Pop();
});
```

Current output: 666555

Desired output: 654321

The reason for removing the message after all processing is finished is to make sure that all messages are processed.

I understand that desired output can be achieved by making subscription synchronous, can the same be achieved for async methods?

Comment: What you're asking for doesn't make sense. Can you please try to describe what your business requirement is rather than the observable you need?

Comment: @Enigmativity: Please see my edits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So here's how I would do it (if I were to stick with using `Task.Run`):

```
var messages = new Stack<int>(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 });

var observable =
    Observable.While<int>(
        () => messages.Count > 0,
        Observable.Defer(() =>
            Observable.FromAsync(() =>
                Task.Run(() => messages.Pop()))));

observable
    .Subscribe(async message =>
    {
        await Task.Delay(2);
        Console.WriteLine(message);
    });
```

This produces runs like:

```
3
2
6
5
1
4
```

Whenever you see `Observable.FromAsync(() => Task.Run(() => /* something */))` you should almost always replace this with `Observable.Start(() => /* something */)`. There's no sense invoking tasks inside an observable if you don't need to.

The code is then:

```
var observable =
    Observable.While<int>(
        () => messages.Count > 0,
        Observable.Defer(() =>
            Observable.Start(() => messages.Pop())));
```

If you want a delay between values and you want them in order then try this:

```
var observable =
    Observable.While<int>(
        () => messages.Count > 0,
        Observable.Defer(() =>
            Observable
                .Start(() => messages.Pop())
                .Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2.0))));

observable
    .Subscribe(message => Console.WriteLine(message));
```

Alternatively there's an option that may be better for you. Try this:

```
var observable =
    Observable
        .Generate(
            0,
            n => messages.Count > 0,
            n => n + 1,
            n => messages.Pop(),
            n => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2.0));

observable
    .Subscribe(message => Console.WriteLine(message));
```

The `.Generate` operator is very powerful.

If you want the first value to be produced immediately it can be changed like this:

```
var observable =
    Observable
        .Generate(
            0,
            n => messages.Count > 0,
            n => n + 1,
            n => messages.Pop(),
            n => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(n == 0 ? 0.0 : 2.0));
```